# I cant return anything in callback function of jQuery bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Can Anybody explain why this happen?

This is my code in a plugin called `something`:

```
(function($){
$.fn.extend({
    something: function(options) {
       // Here I define defaults
       $(this).bind('change', function () { 
          return $(this).each(function() {
          // a function body
          });
       });
     }
});
})(jQuery);
```

and I call this plugin in another js like this:

```
var myarray=new Array();
myarray[0] = $('#selector').something({
regex:/^([\u0600-\u06FF]|\s)*$/,
    // another options
    });
$('#selector').change(function (){
    alert (myarray[0]);
});
```

in every change in my selector it returns me `undefined`.

It completely make me insane. Thanks if anyone can help me.

Edit:

You Can Read My complete code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xPNjV/).

Comment: Can you post the full JavaScript?

Comment: yes I can, Can I post it in comments or I should edit my question?

Comment: Edit your question. At the moment you're replacing your code with comments; the error might be in those areas

Comment: make a simplified plugin demo is jsfiddle.net that displays the issue...also, do selectors exist when you call plugin???

Comment: I edit it and post my complete plugin in jsfiddle. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your plugin you are just attaching a `change` event handler on the element which just runs a loop on all the matched set of elements and returns a jQuery object.

If you want to return something from `something` plugin then the return statement should be outside the event handler.

```
$.fn.extend({
    something: function(options) {
          return $(this).each(function() {
               //Do processing here
          });
     }
});
```

Now you can use this

```
var myarray = $('#selector').something({
        regex:/^([\u0600-\u06FF]|\s)*$/,
        // another options
});
$('#selector').change(function (){
    alert (myarray[0]);
});
```

Note that `myarray` will be an array because jQuery `each` returns a jQuery object which itself is an array of DOM elements.

Answer (score 2):

It is all because your 'something' function does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

One huge problem...  "something" is spelled different in plugin than the jQuery method chain when you call it with your selector

Comment: look at spelling in fiddle, is spelled differnt than above

Comment: Oh I change my plugin name in fiddle to match my plugin name in here, Thats My mistake in fiddle, not in my plugin ;)